# magento showing irrelevant products and products that are under a disabled category

Tags: magento-1.9, products, catalogsearch

magento showing irrelevant products and products that are under a disabled category.

i have on my a category named iphones on my store but this category is set to be disabled
meaning in the "is Active" section i have set it to "no"

when searching the term "iphone" i get irrelevant products and the iphones products in the search results.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the concept of products and categories in Magento.
Disabling a category does not disable the products in that category.
A product can belong to one or many categories (or even no category at all).
You can have products that are visible in the categories but they don't appear in the search.

The products have their own status attribute. If you want to disable some products you can make set the status to `Disabled`. Or you can set their visibility to `Not visible individually`. I recommend you to change the status attribute. The visibility attribute is used for some other things and you might get into trouble if you forget about that.

Comment: he he.. you again answered first! kudos :-)

Answer (score 2):

***Disabling a category will not hide products in that category from the search***.

When you disable a category, then Magento will not show that category in main menu, layered navigation etc. In short, Magento will not use that category in any of category related operations. That means, if you need to access that category, you need to explicitly specify it.

Categories and products are two different entities. So when you disable a category, it will not hide its related products. This is because products have self existence. So as we can disable a category, we can disable a product too.

Just open an existing product through admin. You can see a field that is used to set `visibility`. There are multiple options there. Most probably in your case, it is set with `catalog & search`. It means, this product would be available for all catalog related operations and during search. If you do not want to show that product from search, you need to change this option wisely

Hope that makes sense